# Uneven Income and Estimated Taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, estimated-taxes

My income during the year is uneven. The major part of my income is received during the fourth quarter when I take RMD and also do Roth conversions. I pay estimated taxes during the fourth quarter.

How can I document this to the IRS so that I can avoid the penalty for not paying estimated taxes during the first three quarters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The IRS accounts for this with [Schedule AI - Annualized Income Installment Method](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i2210#en_US_2021_publink1000305556) which is part of Form 2210:

> If your income varied during the year because, for example, you
> operated your business on a seasonal basis or had a large capital gain
> late in the year, you may be able to lower or eliminate the amount of
> one or more required installments by using the annualized income
> installment method. Use Schedule AI to figure the required
> installments to enter on Form 2210, Part III, line 10.